# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'listeners')

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-artisan, laravel-livewire

I was trying out the temporary preview Urls in livewire to preview image before uploading them and I kept getting errors, despite following every step in the example on the livewire website. I have combed through the internet to find solutions to the problem and I have not been able to figure out where the error is. I will appreciate if someone can help me out with this. This was on my local machine and not a live environment.

```
<!--Multiple File Upload -->
<div class="w-full">

    <div class="flex">
        @if($photos)
            Photo Preview:
            <div class="flex bg-blue-200 p-4 rounded-lg">
                @foreach($photos as $photo)
                <img class="w-32 h-32 p-2 rounded-lg" src="{{ $photo->temporaryUrl() }}">
            @endforeach
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
    
    <div class="flex">
        <div wire:loading wire:target="photos">Uploading...</div>
        <form wire:submit.prevent="save">
            <input type="file" wire:model="photos" multiple>
            @error('photos.*') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-300 p-2 rounded-lg">Save Multi Photo</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class MultiUpload extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $photos = [];

    public function save()

    {

        $this->validate([

            'photos.*' => 'image|max:1024', // 1MB Max

        ]);

        foreach ($this->photos as $photo) {

            $photo->store('images');

        }

    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.multi-upload');
    }
}
```

Comment: The error seems to be a JS error. Would you please share the JS part of your code?

Comment: @RouhollahMazarei The javascript part is done by Laravel Livewire which makes it almost impossible for me to sport the error.